# Is $f(x)=\pm\sqrt x$ a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The solution is either that it is not a function or it is only when $x=0$, I don't know which.

Comment: The relation that includes all the couples $(x,\sqrt x)$ and $(x,-\sqrt x)$ is not a function. The relation that only includes $(0,0)$ is indeed a function. Saying "it is a function for $x=0$ and not for $x>0$" has no meaning.

Comment: In order to decide whether it is a function, you have to tell us the domain and the codomain.

Answer (score 3):

A function $f : X \to Y$ defined between a set $X$ and the set $Y$ associate to $x \in X$ a corresponding unique $y=f(x)$ in the codomain $Y$.

So one question you must ask yourself is on what sets do you want to define $f(x)=\pm\sqrt x$? If you want to associate to a positive real a unique real, then you have an issue... However you can define
$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
g : & \mathbb R_+ & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \\
    & x & \longmapsto & (\sqrt{x},-\sqrt{x}) \end{array}$$

**Conclusion**. If you want to define your function from real subsets to reals subsets, then as you noticed, the only possible subset is $\{0\}$ to associate to a unique value a unique value. The $g$ I defined above associate to a unique non negative real a unique COUPLE which can be an answer to your question.

Comment: Well... I'm not sure $\pm u = (-u,u)$ is the most natural or reasonable interpretation.  I was going to write that if $f:\mathbb R_+ \rightarrow P(\mathbb R)$ (the collections of subsets) then $f:x -> \{\sqrt{x},-\sqrt{x}\}$ would be a function.  And the I realized $\pm u = \{u,-u\}$ wasn't nescessary the correct interpretation either.

Answer (score 0):

A function is a mapping (lets call it $f$) from one set (let's call it $A$) to another set (let's call it $B$) so that each element, $x \in A$ is mapped to *precisely* one (not two, not zero) element $f(x) = y \in B$.

In this case $f$ maps $\mathbb R^+$ to $\mathbb R$ (we can write that as $f:\mathbb R^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R$. So that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $f(x)=-\sqrt{x}$.  This is not a mapping that maps every $x$ to precisely *one* value; it maps most values to *two* values.

So it is not a function...

If the domain is $R^+$.  If the mapping has a *different* domain, it could be a function.  If the domain is $A = \{0\}$ then $f$ does map the one and only element of $\{0\}$ to precisely *one* value.  $f:\{0\}\rightarrow \{0\}$ and $f(x)= f(0) = \pm \sqrt{0} = \pm 0 = 0$ and that is a distinct value.  So technically it is a function.

Comment: You are not completely right. Both domain and codomain are not specified in the original question. So we can't really decide whether it is a function or not. If the domain were $\mathbb{R}$ and the codomain were $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, it would be a function.

Comment: It depends on how you interpret "is is only when x = 0".  I interpreted it to mean the domain is {0}.  I suppose it could mean "f is a function only on some values and not on others".  In which case... that's incorrect terminology.

Comment: I decided not to include the following:  If $\pm \sqrt{x} = \{\sqrt{x},-\sqrt{x}\} \subset \mathbb R$ then $f: \mathbb R_+ \rightarrow \text{Powerset}(\mathbb R)$ is a function.  But I chose not to as that would be confusing.

Comment: You are the second person on the post to interpret $\pm u$ as an ordered pair.  Is that standard these days?

Comment: No, I didn't necessarily interpret it as an ordered pair. I just said that the original question is incomplete because domain and codomain are not specified. Most likely, your answer is what the original poster wanted.

Comment: FOr the sake of teaching novices, the domain and codomain is often left implied.  I do not have an issue with that.  Although it does make statements such as "its a function only when x = 0" difficult to interpret.

Comment: Okay, I can agree on that.

Comment: My question about wheter $\pm$ is interpreted as an ordered pair was an irrelevant but curious tangent.  I never that to interpret it as an ordered pair but I often interpret it as a set.  I was just wondering if it was common as I've seen two people do it on this post.

Comment: I agree with everything you say.  We do need to know the domain and I brought them up in the post.  But I allowed the assumption that this is a real function to pervade.  But I hope I gave the impression interpretting the domain and codomain are important.